# xp_cmdshell Date Parameter - Looks for File create Date of last modify date?

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

While deleting files using xp_cmdshell, does the date column look for file creation date or last modified date?

Comment: That depends on what you're executing in the shell. Post your code.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` doesn't take any kind of date argument, it just passes your command to the underlying Windows cmd. So what command are you passing? Why are you doing this kind of thing from SQL Server through `xp_cmdshell`, instead of maintaining your file system independently of SQL Server altogether (e.g. PowerShell)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about using the `FORFILES` command with the `/D` parameter, this uses the last modified date. Type `FORFILES /?` to get more info about this command. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days